# Issue in publishing Android library with multiple modules to Artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory, android-library

I have 2 library modules in my Android project.

```
mainlibrary
  -sublibrary
```

The sublibrary module is being used in mainlibrary. Inside **build.gradle (Module: mainlibrary)**, I have imported the entire sublibrary module -

```
implementation project(':sublibrary')
```

This is how I ship **mainlibrary** as a library using jFrog Artifactory, code present in **build.gradle (Module: mainlibrary)** -

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'in.mikel.reusablelibs'
            version '1.0.4'
            artifactId project.getName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://mikel.jfrog.io/artifactory/'
    publish {
        repository {
            // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            repoKey = 'mikelcl-gradle-release-local'

            username = "***"
            password = "***"
        }
        defaults {
            // Tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be published to Artifactory.
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true

            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

I also want **sublibrary** to be packaged when publishing to Artifactory.

Do I need to write separate information in build.gradle (Module: sublibrary)? How can that be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write a separate build.gradle file. You can configure `sublibrary` in the root build.gradle.
For example:

```
project('sublibrary') {
    publishing {
        publications {
            aar(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'in.mikel.reusablelibs'
                version '1.0.4'
                artifactId project.getName()
                // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
            }
        }
    }
    artifactoryPublish {
        publications(publishing.publications.aar)
    }
}
```

Make sure Artifactory and maven-publish plugins are applied in the `sublibrary` project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Read more:

1. [Example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/gradle-android-example/build.gradle)
2. [Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin)